# Blurring a cubemap in opengl for variance shadowmaps

Tags: c++, opengl, render-to-texture

I got my demo scene up and running with omnidirectional shadowmapping, and now i wanted to go for omnidirectional variance shadowmapping, but unfortunately ive got no idea how to blur a cubemap correctly... Is it sufficient to enable GL_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS and blur every cubemap face or do i need a more sophisticated algorithm here? I've got the cubemap rendered to a fbo color attachment.